# How to access local resources over proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, raspberry-pi, privoxy

So I have a raspberry pi that is acting as a proxy server (privoxy) on my home network. I can access that Pi through Hamachi (I know it's not ideal, but it gets the jobs done well enough). However, I have a NAS and some printers in my home which I would like to access via the proxy, and correct me if I'm wrong, but that should be possible via the proxy correct?

Anyways, I can get the HTTP and the HTTPS traffic to go through my raspberry pi, but I can't make any other traffic do that...

Thanks!

Comment: What about a VPN?

Comment: @Mijago I have a VPN setup with Hamachi, but it doesn't allow access to the NAS